# in MS Word 2007: how can I define a custom keybord shortcut for Display:Final (for reviewing tracked changes)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In MS Word, shortcuts can be defined by user.

Where in the menu would I find to assign a shortcut so that with one keyboard click, I can switch to review view that says 'final'.?

There is in Word Options - Customize - Customize (keyboard shortcuts) an item 'DisplayForReview' but it only accesses the drop down option to select 'final' 'final','showing markup, 'original'.
I want to access the 'final' item within that menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a macro that chooses the view you want, and assign it to a shortcut key.

1. Click the square-shaped macro-recording button at the bottom of Word's application window
2. Type *displayFinal* or a similar name in the macro name text box
3. Click the *Keyboard* icon and choose the shortcut key you want to assign
4. Click *Close* to start recording the macro
5. Click the *Final* item in the review tab's tracking group
6. Click the again square-shaped button at the bottom of Word's application window to stop recording the macro.

Now you can press your shortcut key to re-run this macro choosing the review tab

Comment: I want to mention that new Word macros are saved to *normal.dot* template. This way macros are available in all new word documents. (at least Word 2003 does it this way)

Comment: step 0 is actually enable developer tab via 'word options' -> popular

Comment: @nixda: You can choose to save Word macros in a specific document or the global Normal.dot template. It has supported this for ages now.

Comment: @karan I just wanted to note that this shortcut will be available in every word document due to the fact that normal.dot is selected as default. Nothing more.